# How to fix Logon failure: unknown username or bad password error in ASP.Net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, web-config

I use ftp server. I want to load Image in ftp folder but I have an error.

```
Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

My code is here:

```
public string imagePathStatic = @"\\11.11.111.111\www\images\Products";
ImageCommonTemplate.PostedFile.SaveAs(imagePathStatic + ImageCommonTemplate.FileName);
```

I get error second row. 
I added some code in `web.config` but it doesnt fix.

```
 <identity impersonate="true" userName="websiteName.com" password="websiteftp"/>
```

Actually I dont know what I write `UserName` and `password`  part .

How to fix this error?